# JavaScript - Advisability of closing and returning state in a single method

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

My team is debating the right name for a UI framework JavaScript method that ultimately does the following:

1. It gets the widgets state, if any
2. It removes the widget from the page
3. It returns the retrieved state so that the framework can recreate it
   later

The initially proposed name was 'destroy.'  Some team members feel that people may not expect a method named destroy to return anything.  The name 'getStateAndDestroy' is more descriptive but suggests a single responsbility principle failure.

Thoughts?  Do you see this as more of a naming or design issue?

Comment: I agree that "destroy" implies a single side effect and no return value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` has something very similar, with the name stash.

Comment: Marking this as the answer since it's the higest rated answer (including comments).  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What about 'stow'?

Makes me think of packing it away for possible later use.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the element/widget is being cloned and removed, to be *re-created* at a later point, in the process.

What about: `cloneAndRemove` or `backupAndDestroy` hmmm they're pretty similar to what you've already got though.

Answer (score 1):

How about 'takeAway' or 'takeOut' or 'grab'. Also reminds me a bit of the 'pop' method on a stack. I also think 'remove' is suitable for returning what you removed.